# source command not working in python virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm on garuda linux and create an env folder with `virtualenv env` and then try `source env/bin/activate` but when I do this I get this message:

```
from sourcing file env / bin / activate
source: Error while reading file “env / bin / activate”
```

does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In your command prompt/terminal (**not** in your python file), to activate a virtual environment with `virtualenv`, after creation, you need to type `source env/bin/activate`. Note - you need to make sure your have installed all the correct libraries in your environment beforehand.

It should now be activated as the virtual environment's name should be in brackets before you current directory.

Now navigate to your python file with `cd [file path]`.

Run your python file with `python3 [filename.py]`.

The `from sourcing file env / bin / activate` looks incorrect and should not work.

Comment: @JanZw What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to create a project in python flask and I need to do something with virtualenv for it, I type the command `virtualenv env` and then when I type the command` source env / bin / activate` it pops up:
`from sourcing file env / bin / activate
source: Error while reading file “env / bin / activate”`

Without this source turned on, I can't go any further so I have to turn it on

Comment: @JanZw Oh I see now, read my updated response and it should answer your question.